# Why OMNET++ is unable to compile?

Tags: omnet++

I'm installing OMNET++5.0 on my ubuntu 18, while compiling i get this error message:

```
/usr/include/osgQt/Version:8:2: error: #error "Qt version mismatch detected! Make sure to compile applications using osgQt with the same major Qt version that osgQt has been compiled against."
 #error "Qt version mismatch detected! Make sure to compile applications using osgQt with the same major Qt version that osgQt has been compiled against."
  ^~~~~
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-inconsistent-missing-override’
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-inconsistent-missing-override’
Makefile:1200: recipe for target 'osgcanvasinspector.o' failed
make[3]: *** [osgcanvasinspector.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ros/Desktop/bnj/omnetpp-5.0-src/omnetpp-5.0/out/gcc-release/src/qtenv'
Makefile:37: recipe for target 'qmake' failed
make[2]: *** [qmake] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ros/Desktop/bnj/omnetpp-5.0-src/omnetpp-5.0/src/qtenv'
Makefile:100: recipe for target 'qtenv' failed
make[1]: *** [qtenv] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ros/Desktop/bnj/omnetpp-5.0-src/omnetpp-5.0'
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'allmodes' failed
make: *** [allmodes] Error 2
```

Can any one help me please

Comment: Could you please improve the formatting of your question?

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ 5.0 required Qt4 IIRC. Make sure you have the development libraries for Qt4 installed. Consult the installation manual in the `doc/` folder for details.

Setting the `QT_SELECT` envvar to `4` might also help.

Alternatively, if you don't need 3D (OSG and osgEarth) support for your simulations, you can disable that part in `configure.user`.